# Erro 403 ao acessar código html no FTP

Tags: php, html

Estou com dificuldade para acessar o código **index.html** no FTP. Quando abro ele, aparece uma estrutura em HTML para que apareça escrito "Directory access is forbidden." ao acessa-lo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Preciso alterar o cabeçalho do site, porém não encontro outra alternativa.

Também existe o código **index.php** e **home.php**, porém não encontro a sessão head ou header dentro deles.

Estou começando agora a estudar front-end, principalmente php, então desculpem se estiver perguntando algo tão simples, apenas me foi jogado essa linguagem e tenho pouco tempo de experiência.

Comment: isso não me parece ser relacionado a programação mas sim a autorização, seu user parece não ter as permissões necessárias no index.html

Comment: Era mesmo sobre isso, consegui os acessos por uma pessoa que já passou por isso no meu cargo (estagiário antigo), as coisas aqui estão um pouco jogadas, peço desculpa pela pergunta besta hahah, mas muito obrigado pelo comentário

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.